# How to make an array/table in python from a text file

Tags: python

data.txt file:

```
Lambert 34 10.50
Osborne 22 6.25
Giacometti 5 100.70
```

```
f = input("Enter the file name: ")

f1 = open(f, 'r')

print("Name"  ,   "Hours",   "Total Pay")

for line in f1:
    print(line)
```

current output:

```
Enter the file name: data.txt
Name Hours Total Pay
Lambert 34 10.50

Osborne 22 6.25

Giacometti 5 100.70
```

The issue with this code is that it needs to be printed out in tabular format. With headers of name, hours, total pay, with the contents of the file under it.

I know how to open the file, and print it by line, but I have no idea how I am going to make it like a table format. An example of the output is going to be like this:

```
Enter the file name: data.txt

Name            Hours      Total Pay
Lambert            34         357.00
Osborne            22         137.50
Giacometti          5         503.50
```

How would I do this? I'm almost there, I'm pretty sure I need to make my first print statement longer, and make an array, such as this from another stack overflow post

```
data = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [2, 4, 2]])
```

But the issue is how would I make an array from contents from a text file?

Thank you

Comment: Use `pandas`. `pandas.read_csv('data.txt ', delim_whitespace=True)` should work.

Comment: Did you loot into reading it as a CSV (using `\t` as your separator, it it is tab separated)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data) e.g. [this solution using a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9536060/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea please see the last line of his question he is asking for how to make an array from a text file.

Comment: @google Yes, a dataframe stores its data in an ndarray, plus it supports the column headers OP wants. Either way OP seems to be ultimately asking how to print a table - an ndarray is just one way of doing that.

Comment: @google Oh I see what you're saying - the question I linked doesn't explain how to convert the file to an array. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the [code of @rpanai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901909/how-to-make-an-array-table-in-python-from-a-text-file#comment105931130_59901909) to add columns name to suit your answer

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=['Name', 'Hours', 'Total Pay'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import numpy as np
 data = np.genfromtxt("data.txt")
```

you can do this

if you want to skip the initial lines
    import numpy as np
    data = np.genfromtxt("data.txt")

or you can use **pandas** as well for this purpose

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep=" ")
```

this should also work

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it :

```
filename = input("Enter the file name: ")

items = []
try :
    with open (filename, 'r') as datafile :
        print("Name", "          Hours", "    Total Pay")
        for line in datafile :
            items = line.strip ('\n').split (' ')
            tab1 = ' ' * (18 - (len (items [0]) + len (items [1])))
            tab2 = ' ' * (12 - len (items [2]))
            print (items [0], tab1, items [1], tab2, items [2])
except OSError :
        print ('File ERROR occured.')
        print (filename, ' has not been loaded.')
```

[image: Screen shot of output]